# How to run querys in background thread in javafx 2.1

Tags: java

I have an issue with my app that is a stand alone Java application. I am using the core  java, JDBC and javafx 2.1. I have to show users the number of rows present in a table in the database. For that I am firing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME` in my java code and displaying results in a `tableView` (javafx 2.1). As my database contains large number of tables with large rowcount (number of rows in a table), this process takes a lot of time (30 mins.). With that approach, my `tableview` is stuck and users will be unable to proceed further until the process finishes. I am using the normal `Thread.sleep()` in my code.

I would like to run the process in the background so that users will be able to do other tasks. Users should be notified once the process is done. I have  tried with javafx 2.1 asynchronous but couldn't solve the issue.

Please give me some piece of code that will interact with the db in the background in javafx 2.1.

Thanks& Regards
Salamat

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) as in the [JavaFX Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

This allows you to safely execute code on a background thread and not block the main UI thread.

Here is some [sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967) for accessing a database using a Task.